# Does Microsoft's "stmedit" WFP sample work on Windows 8?

Tags: c, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, wfp, windows-kernel

Microsoft provides a sample called `stmedit` to demonstrate the *Windows Filtering Platform (WFP)* technology. You can look at the sample [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-Filtering-Platform-7b0a3d91).

This sample was also distributed in the Windows 7 DDK and it worked great. However, when trying to run this sample on Windows 8 Release Preview (both 32-bit and 64-bit), it doesn't work.

The code builds fine in Visual Studio 2012 and it can even be installed as a driver. In fact, it even starts up with `net start stmedit` just fine. However, it does not modify any network traffic though it is supposed to replace any occurrence of "rainy" with "sunny" in the the network traffic (I have configured it with its documented registry settings).

Has anyone been able to get this sample working on Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh440281%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> Several changes have been made in the available functions and behavior
>   of the Windows Filtering Platform that begin with Windows 8.
>   Frequently, to take advantage of the new features, you must compile or
>   recompile a callout driver that has the NTDDI_VERSION macro set to
>   NTDDI_WIN8.

Basically, make sure you are checking for the correct NTDDI_VERSION.